# Vectorization with gcc5 gives no information

Tags: c++, g++, vectorization, g++-5

I was trying some vectorisation after upgrading g++ from version 4.8.5 to 5.4.1. With this flags:

```
g++ particles-v3.cpp -o v3 -O3 -msse4.2 -mfpmath=sse -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=5 -ffast-math -m32 -march=native -std=c++11
```

While the same command gives over 4000 lines of detailed information about the vectorization with g++-4.8, with g++-5.4 it does not say anything.

Is there some major change in g++-5 that makes the -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=X unusable, or is there simply somethin wrong in the line? How to change it so that it works?

EDIT:
found out that using `-fopt-info-vec-all` gives exacty the info I wanted. Thus question solved.

Comment: Try adding the `-fopt-info-vec-missed` flag to see information about missed vectorization opportunities.

Comment: That give 283 lines of rather unusably short info. It also does say nothing about the opportunities that did not get missed, while the 4.8 version clearly managed to vectorize at least 1 loop.